# Wordpress iterate for posts but doesn't stop at configured limit

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have a problem with my template, the pagination doesn't appear (I use the plugin wp_pagenavi) and wp doesn't show me all the posts of my blog in the front page.

Here is my code

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 ...
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 ...
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 ...
 <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: There is very little info. You should describe how you are configuring that plugin. Besides your question is not clear: You talk about `doesn't stop at configured limit` and after ` the pagination doesn't appear`. Put more effort in your question...

Comment: what I mean is that it lists all the posts of the blog, and doesn't stops at the post limit setting I configured in settings >> reader

Comment: Do you use a standard WP theme or a custom WP theme?

Comment: It's a custom theme, I'm modifying a working module.